# Use string formatting in pandas DataFrame columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have following data frame (both columns str type):

```
+------+-----------------+
| year | indicator_short |
+------+-----------------+
| 2020 | ind_1           |
| 2019 | ind_2           |
| 2019 | ind_3           |
| N/A  | ind_4           |
+------+-----------------+
```

I would like to add new column which will contain concatenation of two existing columns, but I would like them to be formatted like:

```
+------+-----------------+--------------------+
| year | indicator_short |   indicator_full   |
+------+-----------------+--------------------+
| 2020 | ind_1           | Indicator_1 (2020) |
| 2019 | ind_2           | Indicator_2 (2019) |
| 2019 | ind_3           | Indicator_3 (2019) |
| N/A  | ind_4           | Indicator_4 (N/A)  |
+------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

One thing is coming to my mind is use formatting, something like':

```
df['indicator_full'][df['indicator_short']=='ind_1'] = 'Indicator_1 ({})'.format(df['year'])
```

but it gives wrong result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with string concatenation and formatting the string column as:

```
years = '('+df['year'].astype(str).str.replace(r'.0$','')+')' 
# years =  '('+df['year']+')' if the year col is a string
df['indicator_full   '] = ('Indicator_'+df.indicator_short.str.rsplit('_').str[-1]) \
                                          .str.cat(years, sep=' ')

print(df)
     year indicator_short   indicator_full   
0  2020.0           ind_1  Indicator_1 (2020)
1  2019.0           ind_2  Indicator_2 (2019)
2  2019.0           ind_3  Indicator_3 (2019)
3     NaN           ind_4   Indicator_4 (nan)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for get integers from `indicator_short`, get integers from floats in `year` column and last join together:

```
i = df['indicator_short'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)
y = df['year'].astype('Int64').astype(str).replace('<NA>','N/A')

df['indicator_full'] = 'Indicator_' + i + ' (' + y + ')'
print (df)
0  2020.0           ind_1  Indicator_1 (2020)
1  2019.0           ind_2  Indicator_2 (2019)
2  2019.0           ind_3  Indicator_3 (2019)
3     NaN           ind_4   Indicator_4 (N/A)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.str.cat()` to `concat` the two columns after replacing `ind` with `Indicator` using `.str.replace.`

```
df['indicator_full']=(df.indicator_short.str.replace('ind','Indicator')).str.cat("("+df['year']+ ")", sep=(" ") )
```